# Why does Shia say اشهد ان علیا ولی الله in Adhan (call to prayer)?

Tags: shiism, adhan, ali

Did this practice exist during Prophet's time? Or does this count as an example of unlawful innovation in Islam?

Comment: Well not just that. There are many other varieties of it that are said (hojatullah, khalifatun bila phasl etc; excuse the wrong transliteration) and they vary from culture to culture and place to place. Not sure why.

Comment: No, it wasn't on the time of prophet Mohammed (PBUH). It was invented by Shiism followers. Nobody _sane_ denies how valuable Ali (كرم الله وجهه) is. Also, nobody _sane_ denies that prophet Mohammed (PBUH) is the last messenger sent by Allah (SWT) to all mankind. Hence, there are no prophets nor _Awliya'a_. The true _Awliya'a_ are those who worship Alla (SWT) the way (SWT) deserves. ٍلَآ إِنَّ أَوۡلِيَآءَ ٱللَّهِ لَا خَوۡفٌ عَلَيۡهِمۡ وَلَا هُمۡ يَحۡزَنُونَ (٦٢) ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُواْ وَڪَانُواْ يَتَّقُونَ (٦٣) سورة يونس

Comment: You can see some reasons (why they say like that) by reading the following sites (Of course in Farsi)  www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/59883 or http://www.farsnews.com/newstext.php?nn=13910717000788

Comment: @السید____علی, I added tag 'ali' so that the question shows up in search. "Imam Ali" is not a popular usage by all muslims.

Comment: @infatuated,it is a nice point that you said. your opinion is rational. hopefully, I'll pay more attention to the mentioned matter. God bless you.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Shiite Jurisprudence, this sentence is not an obligatory part of Adhan but mustahab (recommended). However; it is now popularly used as a fixed part of Adhan recitation in most Shiite communities (sometime with variation). But so long as the added part is not considered an integral part of Adhan, it is considered a legitimate practice. The practice of adding certain parts to Adhan has also been common among Sunni Muslims as well.

**The part goes after اشهد ان محمدا رسول الله for stressing the special status Shiites attribute to Ali ibn Abi Talib as Allah's 'friend' (ولي) or 'proof' (حجة) or other titles.**

This is not an innovation though as **some companions of the Holy Prophet used this sentence with the Prophet's approval.**

Examples:

> أخرج أن رجلا دخل على رسول الله (صلى الله عليه واله وسلم) وقال : يا
>   رسول الله إنّ أبا ذر يذكر في الأذان بعد الشهادة بالرسالة الشهادة
>   بالولاية لعلى عليه السلام . قال رسول اللّه‏(صلي الله عليه وآله وسلم )
>   كذلك. ، أو نسيتم قولي في غدير خم : من كنت مولاه فعلي مولاه ) ؟ .
>
> السلافة في أمر الخلافة، ص 32
>
> Once a man saw Prophet (pbuh) and said: O messenger of Allah, Abazar
>   (one of companions) in his Adhan after testifying to your Prophecy
>   testifies to Wiliya of Ali. Prophet said: This is (true)! Did you
>   forget my speech in "Qadir Khom" that every body that accept me as his
>   lord, Ali is his lord too.

And another:

> دخل رجل على رسول الله صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم ، فقال : يا رسول الله
>   ! إني سمعت أمرا لم أسمع قبل ذلك ، فقال صلى الله عليه واله وسلم : ما هو
>   ؟ قال : سلمان قد يشهد في أذانه بعد الشهادة بالرسالة ، الشهادة بالولاية
>   لعلي (عليه السلام)  ، قال (صلي الله عليه وآله وسلم ): سمعت خيرا.
>
> السلافة في أمر الخلافة، ص 32.
>
> Once a man saw prophet (pbuh) and said: O messenger of Allah, I heard
>   something that I didn't hear that before; Prophet (pbuh) asked: what
>   is that? The man answered: Salman (one of companions) in his Adhan
>   after testifying to your Prophecy testifies to Ali's Wiliaya **Prophet
>   (pbuh) said: you heard a good thing.**

Comment: Have you got any _Hadith_ supporting this?

Comment: Slam Alaikom brother. what's your meaning of hadith? the above sentences of prophet are not enough?

Comment: all your Answers are to the point. :) @FatemehBaqeri

Answer (score -1):

*Shiite* scholar *Al-Sadouq* had refused this addition in his book (من لا يحضره الفقيه).

> أنه " حكى لهما الاذان فقال: الله أكبر، الله أكبر، الله أكبر أكبر، أشهد أن لا إله إلا الله، أشهد أن لا إله إلا الله، أشهد أن محمدا رسول الله، أشهد أن محمدا رسول الله، حي على الصلاة، حي على الصلاة، حي على الفلاح، حي على الفلاح، حي على خير العمل، حي على خير العمل، الله أكبر، الله أكبر، لا إله إلا الله، لا إله إلا الله، والاقامة كذلك"(1).
>   ولا بأس أن يقال في صلاة الغداة على أثر حي على خير العمل " الصلاة خير من النوم " مرتين للتقية.
>
> وقال مصنف هذا الكتاب رحمه الله: **هذا هو الاذان الصحيح لا يزاد فيه ولا ينقص منه، والمفوضة لعنهم الله قد وضعوا أخبارا وزادوا في الاذان** " محمد وآل محمد خير البرية " مرتين، وفي بعض رواياتهم بعد أشهد أن محمدا رسول الله " أشهد أن عليا ولي الله " مرتين، ومنهم من روى بدل ذلك " أشهد أن عليا أمير المؤمنين حقا " مرتين ولا شك في أن عليا ولي الله وأنه أمير المؤمنين حقا وأن محمدا وآله صلوات الله عليهم خير البرية، ولكن ليس ذلك في أصل الاذان، وإنما ذكرت ذلك ليعرف بهذه

[[290] من لا يحضره الفقيه](http://almoqdsalghorayfi.com/Alkotb-Al2rb3a/Mn-La-Ehdhrh-Alfqih/fakeeh1/html/ara/books/faqih/faqih-1/a46.html)

Note that حي على خير العمل is another addition to *Athan* and الصلاة خير من النوم is correct and only mentioned in *Fajr* prayer.

Comment: Please note that Al Sadouq's opinion on this subject is a minority opinion among Shiite scholars. The consensus of the great majority of shiite scholars is that the addition of اشهد أن علی ولی اللهis mustahab. As for حي علي خير العمل Shiites also prove it to be part of Adhan and similarly provide their own evidences -- mainly hadiths of the Holy Prophet transmitted through His Purified Household or sometimes even Sunni sources -- to prove their view.

Comment: @infatuated oh, now his opinion is a minority. "_sometimes even Sunni sources_" you won't find such a thing in Sunni resources unless _fabricated_.

Comment: not now! Please note that Al Sadouq is a 4th century Shiite scholar and Shiite jurisprudence didn't fix at that point. There have been major revisions and completions as later scholars could make ijtihad over a much larger pool of Shiite hadiths and new rules of ijtihad. And there has been a consensus for now centuries over the format of Adhan. And as for Sunni sources you don't seem to have th eauthority to determine which hadith is fabricated. But if you do I'm interested to know why you think the hadiths quoted in Fatemeh's answer above are fabricated.

Comment: @infatuated because it has no "sanad سند" and I couldn't find it in Sunnah's books.

Comment: about the first part of your comment, yes and I wrote that اشهد ان علیا ولی الله is not a main part but we have: « الا انه لا بأس بذكر ذلك لا على سبيل الجزئية عملاً بالخبر المزبور ولا يقدح مثله فى الموالاة و الترتيب، بل هى كالصلاة على محمد عند سماع اسمه... بل لو لا تسالم الأصحاب لأمكن دعوى الجزئية بناء على صلاحيّه العموم لمشروعية الخصوصية. و الامر سهل.»
جواهر الكلام 9: 87.     and we have in Biharol-Anvar that is one of the most trusty books in shia:وأقول : لا يبعد كون الشهادة بالولاية من الأجزاء المستحبة للأذان ، لشهادة الشيخ والعلامة والشهيد وغيرهم بورود الأخبار بها .
بحار الانوار ج 84 ص 111

Comment: @FatemehBaqeri this applies for those who believe/witness "Al Wilaya الولاية". It does not apply to those who believe that Ali (كرم الله وجهه) is the 4th _chalipha rashidi_. Moreover, you haven't mentioned any _hadith_ supporting your alibi(s).

Comment: I don't want to establish anything brother, I just wanted to say this part of Adhan is Mastahab, is not Haram or innovation and is not against prophet order. I NEVER MEAN SAYING THIS PART OF ADHAN IS VAJIB (NECESSARY).

Comment: ABOUT حی علی خیر العمل PLEASE SEE THIS:     http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17885/%D8%AD%DB%8C-%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C-%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84-is-a-part-of-adhan-or-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%88%D9%85/17886#17886